# Cannot Create Azure A series VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am creating my first VM on Azure.  I just need the very basic VM, which is A series as listed in this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/.  However, when I actually tried to create a VM, I didn't see the list anymore.  I went to Compute->Windows Server 2012 R2 DataCenter, but all options started from DS1-V2.  I didn't see any A series VMs.  Then there is this new price calculator: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/.  It did show the A series VMs, but didn't actually create one for you after purchase.  All these are very confusion and misleading.  Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.   This question, while a good one, isn't really about programming, its the sort of thing you're likely to get a better response direct from Microsoft by submitting an Azure support ticket.  https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportrequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

1. For creating `A` series VM, please make sure that you have selected `HDD` as the hard disk type and not `SSD`.
2. When choosing the size in the portal, by default it only shows recommended items and not the full list. Please click on `View all` link (next to `Recommended`) link to see all supported VM sizes.

Comment: Changed to HDD and clicked on "View all".  It worked.  Thanks.